# How to push and pull data to KNIME

Tags: python, web, frontend, backend, knime

I have a front end website which asks questions and then collects this information in JSON format. I am looking to push this data to my KNIME decision tree workflow, then ultimately push the results back to the front end. This should display some type of output. I am hoping to this in REAL time.

My question is how do I get my front end to communicate with KNIME. I would like to use the simplest method for this.

All suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: You can check this out: https://www.knime.com/blog/the-knime-server-rest-api